# Are there any cases where type aliases might be error-prone or not perfoming as expected?

Tags: c++, c, winsock

I was just reading the intro of [Beej's Guide to Network Programming](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/intro.html) and the guide mentioned that few edits should be done in order to make the examples work on Windows.

[In the same section](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/intro.html#windows), a piece of code is given, now without any further ado, why that code says the following?

```
WSADATA wsaData;   // if this doesn't work
//WSAData wsaData; // then try this instead
```

I've checked them in Visual Studio and MSDN, `WSADATA` is indeed a type alias for `WSAData` struct.

Now, why the first one might *not work*? This left me puzzled (doubtful, actually). Could it have something with the development environment like the version of VS or Windows SDK?

**Disclaimer:** He was ranting about Windows just a few lines back...

P.S. Shouldn't we use the socket 2.2 version instead of 2.0 (used in his code) as well?

Comment: I suspect this is a name-space issue with `typedef WSAData struct ... WSADATA` in C vs. C++ which handles things differently.  IMO, better to ask for an answer in one language only.

Comment: This isn't an issue with use of type aliases.   It is an issue that the API used under windows for network programming has some similarities and some incompatibilities with the APIs commonly used under various flavours of unix.      Beej prefers unix, so bags windows.   A similar guide written by a windows zealot, could equally bag unix in the same way.   My view is that networking APIs are ugly under both windows and unix, and developers who need to target both systems either need to suck it up or define an API that works on both.

Comment: @Peter I suspected this much. Also, believe me, I **do** favor unix over windows, it's just this time I should stick with windows.